# compare first two columns of two csv files

Tags: csv

I have two csv files, 1a.csv and 2a.csv

`1a.csv` looks like this:

```
 SKU, QTY
KA005-001,17
KA006-001,46
KA010-001,25
KA014-001,42`
```

`2a.csv` looks like this:

```
 SKU, QTY
KA006-001,81
KA009-001,25
KA010-001,18
KA014-001,45`
```

I need to get a new file like this `3a.csv`:

```
 SKU, QTY
KA005-001,17 
KA006-001,81 (i.e. 2a.csv QTY)
KA009-001,25
KA010-001,18 (i.e. 2a.csv QTY)
KA014-001,45 (i.e. 2a.csv QTY)`
```

Could someone help me with this problem as well ? Thank you very much.

Comment: always `2a` for duplicates?

Comment: @ Stephen Rauch ...2a.csv is my main file, rows not in 2a will be put there from 1a, 2a QTY column has a precedence over 1a

Comment: What's going on with the tags? Why is it tagged [tag:python], [tag:bash] and [tag:perl] simultaneously? I see no code in *any* of the languages. You should at least make an attempt by yourself and ask about coding issues here. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.

Comment: @iBug ...while posting a question it was requesting me to put some tags, so i did. i was trying so many things like for example `diff  -W999 --side-by-side 1a.csv 2a.csv | sed '/^[^\t]*\t\s*|\t\(.*\)/{s//\1 U/;b};/^\([^\t]*\)\t*\s*<$/{s//\1 D/;b};/^.*>\t\(.*\)/{s//\1 N/;b};d'`

Comment: @Emc2 Can't you just tag [tag:csv] instead of 3 irrelevant ones? I've corrected it for you now.

Comment: @iBug ...i searched a lot and tried different code snippets.

Comment: @Emc2 You should add tags that are relevant to your question. I see no effort in it in those languages, so the tags are irrelevant.

Comment: @iBug ...absolutely, will do csv tag

Comment: @Emc2: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: 
Using pandas you concatenate your two csv files (say cs1 is the dataframe with your first csv and cs2 the dataframe with your second csv):

```
import pandas as pd
cs1 = pd.read_csv('1a.csv')
cs2 = pd.read_csv('2a.csv')
cs3 = pd.concat([cs1, cs2])
```

Now the two dataframes are concatenated on top of one another:

```
 SKU, QTY
KA005-001,17
KA006-001,46
KA010-001,25
KA014-001,42
KA006-001,81
KA009-001,25
KA010-001,18
KA014-001,45
```

You can now just use `drop_duplicates()` by subsetting to column 'SKU' to remove the duplicate entries. Since you only want to keep the entries from cs2 and remove those from cs1, use the option `keep='last'`:

```
cs3 = cs3.drop_duplicates(subset='SKU', keep='last')
```

You now get:

```
 SKU, QTY
KA005-001,17 
KA006-001,81
KA009-001,25
KA010-001,18
KA014-001,45
```

which you can save to csv:

```
cs3.to_csv('3a.csv')
```

Comment: @user2969402...i tried but got this error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "problem2_solution.py", line 9, in <module>
    cs3 = cs3.drop_duplicates(subset='SKU', keep='last')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3535, in drop_duplicates
    duplicated = self.duplicated(subset, keep=keep)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3582, in duplicated
    labels, shape = map(list, zip(*map(f, vals)))
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack`

Comment: can you post the first few lines of cs3 ?

Comment: ...`#!/usr/local/lib/python

import pandas as pd

cs1 = pd.read_csv('1a.csv')
cs2 = pd.read_csv('2a.csv')
cs3 = pd.concat([cs1, cs2])

cs3 = cs3.drop_duplicates(subset='SKU', keep='last')

cs3.to_csv('3a.csv')`   this is my script as per your instructions

Comment: but cs3 never produced this new file 3a.csv inside the folder

Comment: `import pandas as pd cs1 = pd.read_csv('1a.csv') cs2 = pd.read_csv('2a.csv') cs3 = pd.concat([cs1, cs2]) ` just use this part first and then type `cs3` and post the first few lines of what your console outputs here. I want to check if pandas properly reads you csv file. There can be problems depending on what punctuation you use or with headers/indexes.

Comment: i tried this: `#!/usr/local/lib/python

import pandas as pd

cs1 = pd.read_csv('1a.csv')
cs2 = pd.read_csv('2a.csv')
cs3 = pd.concat([cs1, cs2])`  ....and all good, my console outputs no errors, i.e there is no output

Comment: I've got this, than I run the script `,SKU,QTY
0,KA005-001,17
0,KA006-001,81
1,KA009-001,25
2,KA010-001,18
3,KA014-001,45
` No needed first column

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awk this way

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{print "SKU,QTY"}NR>1{a[$1] = $2}END{for (i in a) if(i != "SKU")print i","a[i]}' 1a.csv 2a.csv
```

or bash 4 with associative arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A astr

getDataFromFile(){
    while IFS=, read -r col1 col2
    do
        if [ "$col1" != "SKU" ] && [ "$col1" != "" ]
        then
            (( astr[$col1] = col2 ))
        fi
    done < $1 
}

getDataFromFile 1a.csv
getDataFromFile 2a.csv

echo "SKU,QTY"
for i in "${!astr[@]}"
do   
    echo "$i,${astr[$i]}"
done | sort -t : -k 2n
```

or Python(also usage of associative arrays):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

a={}
def getDataFromFile(fname):
    f = open(fname)
    for line in f:
       fields = line.strip().split(",")
       a[fields[0]] = fields[1]

getDataFromFile('1a.csv')
getDataFromFile('2a.csv')

for key, value in a.iteritems():
    print key+","+value
```

https://github.com/tigertv/stackoverflow-answers